# is it possible to read the xml data of an XIB file

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to parse the XML of an XIB file? I want to return the content of an XIB file as `NSString` so that I can parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because the XIB file is compiled during the build and is no longer XML when placed into the app bundle.  The original XIB file is not part of the app bundle.